# Unable to save Webhook Data received using ASP.NET C# Web Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webforms, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I am trying to build a JSON webhook, I have configured the receiver and webhook handler. I am trying to save the POST data received from webhook to my SQL server.But I couldnt.

When i make the HTTP request to the webhook URL, I have 200 OK response and debug points in webhook handler never hit. I am unable to figure out the problem, Please help me out.

Below is my webhook handler and receiver configuraition and Global.ascx

WEBHOOK HANDLER

```
public CustomWebHookHandler()
{
    this.Receiver = "genericjson";
}

public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
{
    //CustomNotifications notifications = context.GetDataOrDefault<CustomNotifications>();
    //return Task.FromResult(true);
    JObject dataJObject = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();
    Console.Write("Data rx from webhook  " + dataJObject.ToString()); 
    return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

RECEIVER

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {


        var controllerType = typeof(WebHookReceiversController);


        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks(); 
    }
}
```

Global.ascx

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Debug Point Never reached the Webhook Handler method ExecuteAsync Where I am trying to save the data to a file or to Database. I am new to this, If some one got ant idea please help me out.Thanks

When I make HTTP POST Request to the Webhook URL, I have noticed the below on the Visual Studio :

[iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Registered 'IWebHookReceiver' instances with the following names: genericjson, custom.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'genericjson' and id 'i'.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Registered configuration setting 'GenericJson' for ID 'i''.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Registered configuration setting 'GenericJson' for ID 'z''.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '' (0x376c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5IAP.jpg)